# React Native:How to get key value?

Tags: react-native

i am new in react native i want to get key value.Let me know how to do this?

```
<TouchableOpacity key={text}  onPress={this.Click.bind(this)}> </TouchableOpacity>
    Click()
    {
    // how to get key value here.
    }
```

Comment: Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name

Comment: what is the usage of key?Where we can use key?

Comment: [List and Keys - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

In react, keys are used to track components. While there is no way to access it from inside, if you are the one determining your keys, you can do it by passing the same key to your onPress function by wrapping it in another function. Example;

```
<TouchableOpacity
    key={text}
    onPress={(other_argument) => (this.Click.bind(this))(text, other_argument)}
> </TouchableOpacity>

Click(key, other_argument) {
    console.log(key);
}
```